# RODBC Connection becomes invalid

Tags: r, rodbc

I am testing a new database system using a provided ODBC driver and the `RODBC` package.

**The issue I am encountering is that after only a few queries (all within the span of 2~3 minutes or less), the connection is no longer recognized as valid by R.**

Specifically, it is only a single `C` function in the `RODBC` package, `RODBCcheckchannel` which is complaining.  It is called indirectly by `sqlQuery()`

---

The first line of `RODBC::sqlQuery` calls

```
if (!odbcValidChannel(channel))
    stop("first argument is not an open RODBC channel")
```

`odbcValidChannel` **checks three properties of `channel`**.
I can confirm that the two checks done in `R` return `TRUE`.
It is the last check, `.Call(RODBC:::C_RODBCcheckchannel, channel, attr(channel, "id"))` which returns `FALSE`

Source code for `RODBCcheckchannel` is as follows

```
SEXP RODBCcheckchannel(SEXP chan, SEXP id)
{
    SEXP ptr = getAttrib(chan, install("handle_ptr"));
    pRODBCHandle thisHandle = R_ExternalPtrAddr(ptr);

    return ScalarLogical(thisHandle && TYPEOF(ptr) == EXTPTRSXP &&
       thisHandle->channel == asInteger(chan) &&
       thisHandle->id == asInteger(id));
}
```

I have tried using `R -d valgrind`, but since the `C` code is not crashing *per-se*, this was not helpful.

**Can someone shed some light as to why `.Call(RODBC:::C_RODBCcheckchannel, channel, attr(channel, "id"))` returns `TRUE` for a short while then returns `FALSE`?**
Does it have something to do with the handle?

*(Apologies for the lack of reproducible exmample, as that would require access to a very specific database system)*

Comment: Guessing: perhaps the DB is closing the connection?

Comment: Simply -- there's not enough info here. ODBC has a tracing/logging facility -- you should enable this, try to recreate the error, and see what you find. Lacking that... Minimally, troubleshooting issues such as this usually requires knowing the name and version of both the DBMS and Driver in question, sometimes the host OS on both sides, and various other details ... which we don't have here.

Comment: The only thing I can offer is that I have experienced remote DBs closing connections after a period of time, but I've seen that (with Oracle) using RODBC and ROracle, and it's always the remote DB doing it.

Comment: ODBC connections have a default connection timeout value that depends on the driver and database, e. g. 30, 60 or 120 seconds. If you do not use the the connection for this amount of seconds the connection will be closed automatically ("connection" is called "channel" in RODBC).

Answer (score 0):

Can you add tracing to the following code? If so, it would useful to print out the values for thisHandle, TYPEOF(ptr), thisHandle->channel, thisHandle->id to see what has changed?

```
SEXP RODBCcheckchannel(SEXP chan, SEXP id)
{
    SEXP ptr = getAttrib(chan, install("handle_ptr"));
    pRODBCHandle thisHandle = R_ExternalPtrAddr(ptr);

    return ScalarLogical(thisHandle && TYPEOF(ptr) == EXTPTRSXP &&
       thisHandle->channel == asInteger(chan) &&thisHandle->id == asInteger(id)); 
}
```